# Automate Internal Product Number Generation with MySQL 8.0 Triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I am not very experienced with the schema side of SQL and I must create a system to generate internal product numbers when new rows are inputted into the database. I have decided using SQL triggers would be the best way to do this, instead of external programming because it seems neater and doable inside SQL.

Example internal product number: 101-001

The internal product number has two parts, I am calling `group_id` and `product_id` respectively. `group_id` is related to `category_id` (how it is stored in database) and there is a table I am using to connect these, `PartCategory`. The `product_id` is incremental in each `group_id`, but if one row was removed, they are expected to continue as if none had been removed, I think MAX is appropriate.

Here is an example of the two tables I am working with:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Part;
CREATE TABLE Part (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    category_id INT,
    internalPartNumber VARCHAR(255),
    name VARCHAR(255),
    createdate DATETIME,
    group_id INT,
    product_id INT
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PartCategory;
CREATE TABLE PartCategory (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    category_id INT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    internal_id INT,
    last_product_id INT
);


INSERT INTO PartCategory (internal_id, category_id, name) VALUE (101, 2, 'category1');
INSERT INTO PartCategory (internal_id, category_id, name) VALUE (102, 3, 'category2');

INSERT INTO Part (category_id, name, createdate, group_id, product_id) VALUE (2,   'screw', NOW(), 101, 1);
INSERT INTO Part (category_id, name, createdate, group_id, product_id) VALUE (2, 'spanner', NOW(), 101, 2);
INSERT INTO Part (category_id, name, createdate, group_id, product_id) VALUE (3,  'hammer', NOW(), 102, 1);
INSERT INTO Part (category_id, name, createdate, group_id, product_id) VALUE (3,   'paint', NOW(), 102, 2);

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER add_group_id BEFORE INSERT ON Part
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Part
    LEFT JOIN PartCategory
    ON Part.category_id = PartCategory.category_id
    SET NEW.group_id = PartCategory.internal_id
    WHERE Part.group_id IS NULL;
    
    UPDATE Part
    SET NEW.product_id = MAX(Part.product_id) OVER(PARTITION BY Part.category_id ORDER BY createdate)
    WHERE NEW.product_id IS NULL;
    
    SET NEW.internalPartNumber = CONCAT(RIGHT(NEW.group_id+1000, 3),'-',RIGHT(NEW.product_id+1000, 3))
    WHERE NEW.internalPartNumber IS NULL;
END; //
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO Part (category_id, name, createdate) VALUE (2, 'bolt', NOW());
INSERT INTO Part (category_id, name, createdate) VALUE (3, 'metal', NOW());

SELECT internalPartNumber, name FROM Part
ORDER BY internalPartNumber;
```

However inside triggers I cannot use the table Part because it invoked the trigger. I am at a loss of how to do this. The first six inserts represent the data inputted into the database via a script, these ones I can set any rows, the last two represent the data that would be inputted by the users (the ones the triggers need to work on).

From this example I would like to see:

```
internalPartNumber | name
101-001            | screw
101-002            | spanner
101-003            | bolt
102-001            | hammer
102-002            | paint
102-003            | metal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_Part
BEFORE INSERT
ON Part
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.internalPartNumber = CONCAT( ( SELECT internal_id 
                                       FROM PartCategory 
                                       WHERE category_id = NEW.category_id ),
                                     '-',
                                     ( SELECT LPAD(1 + COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0), 3, '0')
                                       FROM Part
                                       WHERE category_id = NEW.category_id ) );
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=58fd1bc356c0a2f771d8160235be3c0c

Comment: @harrygdt Take into account that the code does not check: category presence, internal number oversize.

Comment: Yes, I see. This shouldnt be an issue in my case, but I'll make a note for the next person to use this in the database.

Comment: This has a race condition. Two concurrent sessions that insert will see the same `COUNT(*)` and therefore allocate the same internal part number.